# Store List Elements to an Excel Spreadsheet (JXL)

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I have written selenium code that navigates to a site that generates up to (100) random names.

The URL is http://random-name-generator.info/random/?n=100&g=1&st=2

Upon successful page load, the names display in a list in the following format:

```
<ol class="nameList">

<li>
Woodrow Gordon  
</li>
```

What I would like to do next is this:

1. Store the names to an Excel Spreadsheet (I would like to use JXL to accomplish this)

Answer (score 0):

To extract the names, I would do it by following your code with:

`List<WebElement> names = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".nameList li");`

It finds all `<li>` elements nested in the `<ol> class="nameList">` element.

What remains is to iterate over this list and put your names into your Excel file with JXL. You did not specify how they should be arranged so I cannot help you further.